# Why is a Constant added to front?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponentiation

I made the differential equation : $$dQ = (-1/100)2Q dt$$

I separate it and get: $\int_a^b x (dQ/Q) =  \int_a^b x (-2/100)dt$

this leads me to: $\log(|Q|) = (-t/50) + C$

I simplify that to $Q = e^{-t/50}$

My TI-Nspire differential equation solver, however, gives me: $Q = Ce^{-t/50}$

I'm confused as to why the calculator is multiple my answer with a constant and which one is the correct answer.

Comment: Your solution is (should be) $Q=\exp(-\frac{t}{50}+C)$ which equals $Q=\tilde{C}\exp(-\frac{t}{50})$ where $\tilde{C}=\exp{C}$.

Comment: You had a constant in $\ln|q|=-t/50+C$. Where did that go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log(|Q|)=(−t/50)+C

$e^{log(|Q|} = e^{\frac{-t}{50}+C}$

$Q = e^{\frac{-t}{50}} e^{C}$

Now you need to recognized that $e^{C}$ is just another constant, so we substitute $e^{C}$ with just C.

You could say that $C_1 = e^{C}$ and use $C_1$, but most people say use C and gloss over this distinction.

$Q = C e^{\frac{-t}{50}}$

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the $$C$$s in the above equations don't matter, as the only equation that's used is the one with $$q = $$. thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(x)=t+c$ implies that $x=e^{t+c}=e^ce^t=ke^t$ where $k=e^c$.

Comment: Oh I see, so this is a different kind of constant. so the c that my calculator should be $$C_1 = e^(C_0)$$

Answer (score 1):

In your second to last step $ln(|q|) = (-t/50) + C$ you get $e^{\ln|q|}=e^{-t/50+C}$ so $|q|=e^{-t/50}e^C$ which can be stated as $q=\pm Ce^{-t/50}$ or $q= Ce^{-t/50}$.

Comment: when I go to find what the value of my constant is, do I set that $$C_1 = e^(c_0)$$?

Comment: @ OP: note that if you write $Q(t)=C\exp(-t/50)$ then $Q(0)=C\exp(-0/50)=C$ so that $C=Q(0)$. This allows you to write $Q(t)=Q(0)\exp(-t/50)$.

Comment: @KimJongUn gotcha thanks, I think I made my differential equation wrong though, because at t=0, Q should also be 0, which means C = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Even though $\log(|Q|) = (-t/50) + C$ implies $|Q| = e^{-t/50+c} \iff Q= \pm e^{-t/50+c}=\pm e^{-t/50}e^c$,
but $e^c$ is a constant raised to a constant, which is (...you guessed right) a constant! So $Q= \pm C e^{-t/50}$ where $C=e^c$